# Sending NEC IR signals makes LED strip blink

Tags: esp8266, ir, nodemcu

I'm trying to make my ESP8266 (running NodeMCU meaning Arduino code gets compiled on it). I followed a guide and now I can read the IR codes from my remote using my Arduino UNO, and then send them to the LED strip. So far sending it actually works, but it blinks REALLY fast.

Some part of me tells me it's trying to send it twice or the radio frequency is wrong. For TVs and so on, it doesn't really matter, as you can't turn on and off a TV instantly. You can with this LED strip though. This is how I send my NEC signal to the strip:

```
irsend.sendNEC(0xFF02FD, 433);
```

433 is the frequency (433 kHz), as I read that's the most common frequency these LED strips work at. The entire code I used [can be found here](https://github.com/JZ-SmartThings/SmartThings/blob/master/Devices/TVDevice/IRremoteESP8266-Using5Volts/IRSender5V.ino). Do you think I have a frequency issue? I have tried a lot of different frequencies and they all seem to do the same thing.

Also, when I try to send the exact same NEC signal to my receiver, I get two different results. It is only being sent one time as well. Here is what I receive:

**Using the actual receiver**:

```
Decoded NEC(1): Value:FF02FD (32 bits)
Raw samples(68): Gap:51848
  Head: m8750  s4550
0:m450 s650 1:m450 s650      2:m450 s650    3:m450 s650      
4:m500 s650 5:m450 s650      6:m450 s650    7:m450 s650      
8:m450 s1750    9:m500 s1750         10:m450 s1750  11:m450 s1750        
12:m500 s1750   13:m450 s1750        14:m450 s1750  15:m500 s1750        

16:m450 s650    17:m450 s650         18:m450 s650   19:m450 s650         
20:m500 s600    21:m500 s650         22:m450 s1750  23:m450 s650         
24:m450 s1750   25:m500 s1700        26:m500 s1750  27:m450 s1750        
28:m500 s1700   29:m500 s1750        30:m450 s650   31:m450 s1750        

32:m450
Extent=66900
Mark  min:450    max:500
Space min:600    max:1750
```

**Using `irsend.sendNEC(0xFF02FD, 433)`**

```
Decoded Unknown(0): Value:0 (0 bits)
Raw samples(38): Gap:18088
  Head: m8850  s4550
0:m500 s1750    1:m500 s650      2:m450 s650    3:m500 s650      
4:m500 s650 5:m450 s650      6:m500 s650    7:m450 s1800         
8:m450 s700 9:m450 s1800         10:m450 s1800  11:m450 s1800        
12:m450 s1800   13:m450 s1800        14:m450 s1800  15:m450 s650         

16:m500 s1750   17:m500
Extent=43200
Mark  min:450    max:500
Space min:650    max:1800
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention: 0xFF02FD is the signal power/on/off button. If I change the 0xFF02FD to anything else (like 0xFF18E7 to make it yellow), the LED strip will just blink.

Comment: Huh, are you controlling a ledstrip or a TV (by ir)?

Comment: @Paul LED strip :) But as you can see below, I managed to fix this.

Comment: Ah wait, you've got an ledstripcontroller with IR? Or are you actually blinking a whole strip in IR signals? xd

Comment: 38kHz is the most common for IR. For RF remotes it's 433MHz. So I think that where you got that number from.

Answer (score 1):

32 kHz seems to be the winner. Now all my codes work! Damn, if I only had read that ONE SITE that showed it haha.